# Is it possible to reduce notification time showing in Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am using bellow code to show a notification on my Android phone. I want to reduce the time which uses to shows the notification. Now, it spends about 2 seconds for showing, then it is hidden. I want to reduce the time from 2 seconds to 1 second. Is it possible?

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("Notification")
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager(context);
notificationManager.notify(SAFER_DISCONNECTED_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Now, it spends about 2 seconds for showing, then it is hidden.

There is no particular guarantee regarding the amount of time that a `Notification` will be shown in heads-up mode, which I assume is what you are referring to.

For example, by default it will be shown for 0 seconds on Android 4.4 and earlier, which does not natively support heads-up notifications. However, a user could install an app with a `NotificationListenerService`, and that service could display the notification however, and for however long, it wants.

> Is it possible?

No, sorry. That is under the control of the code that displays the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are shown by android, and there are **no permissions** for applications for changing theirs notifications preview time-life in non rooted devices.

But if the content of the notifications are not important, you can cancel notifications programmatically after one second:

1- create a time for doing your task after one second:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new   Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //your code for cancel notification(s)
                }
           });
        }
    }, 
1000);
```

2- you can cancel a notification:

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nMgr.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
```

or cancel all notifications in given context:

```
nMgr.cancelAll();
```